Build Failed: Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings'] in React Native v0.76
I'm developing a React Native app with the latest version (v0.76), and I'm running into an error when trying to start my Android build. Here is the error message I'm seeing:
info Opening app on Android...
info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'D:\work\gyan app\gyanapp\android\settings.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings']
> java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (D:\work\gyan app\gyanapp\android\.gradle\8.10.2\dependencies-accessors\569c8b261a8a714d7731d5f568e0e5c05babae10-d00c142d-b508-4dbf-96ba-b59eb9ee1c5a) to immutable location (D:\work\gyan app\gyanapp\android\.gradle\8.10.2\dependencies-accessors\569c8b261a8a714d7731d5f568e0e5c05babae10)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 42s

I have tried cleaning gradlew but it didn't work
./gradlew clean


I faced the same issue. you may try this;

Check if you have a local.properties file in your Android folder
If not, create a new file named local.properties (without any extension)
Add this line to the file:

sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\[YourUsername]\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk

